# How to remove Error message: No such file or directory found Python?

Tags: python, file-handling

path="C:\Users\Manav\Desktop\txtfile.txt"
f = open(path,mode='r')
The file (txtfile.txt) is on the desktop. I have tried a few things now but still the error persists.I use jetbeans pycharm. Used double '' too.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Close to a typo: a backslash is a quoting character so it must be doubled: `C:\\Users\\Manav\\Des...`

Comment: Note that ``\t`` is a tab character. It is not the two characters ``\`` and ``t``.

Comment: path="C:\\Users\\Manav\\Desktop\\txtfile.txt"
f = open(path,mode='r')
Tried this too
Name of the file is txtfile.txt. .

Comment: If the linked question does not solve your problem, please [edit] your question to provide more details. Does ``os.path.exists(path)`` return true? Do you have permission to read the file? Also, consider to use this opportunity to properly format the code shown. See the [mcve] and [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: os.path.exists(path)
returns false. I'll edit the question.